# With iLife 11, considerations of slide shows

Tags: ilife, slideshow

I have to turn a big stack of images into one of those somewhat sappy slide shows with music.

Google shows various advice from various points in time. The last advice I found was iDVD. Is that the right path to launch off on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iMovie has the "Ken Burns" effect (the actual name in the application!), designed specifically to do slow panning across images that dissolve into others, etc. It's very flexible and quite powerful.

iDVD is definitely not what you want. If nothing else, it hasn't actually been updated in years, and both iPhoto and iMovie significantly outshine it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not at all. iPhoto has [great slideshow capabilities](http://www.apple.com/ilife/iphoto/#new-slideshows).

[Lots of examples on YouTube.](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=iphoto+11+slideshow&aq=f)

No need to involve DVDs; or slow, aging software like iDVD.